# How to set datetime format in jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format, jquerydatetimepicker

I need to set a datetimepicker in the specific format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt` for example `13/03/2024 2.30 PM`. But, I am getting `13/03/2024 14.30`. I also can not set the minutes. It only shows the hours like `11.00`, `12.00` and so on.

I tried in this way.
cdn links

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" integrity="sha512-bYPO5jmStZ9WI2602V2zaivdAnbAhtfzmxnEGh9RwtlI00I9s8ulGe4oBa5XxiC6tCITJH/QG70jswBhbLkxPw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

html

`<input type='text' id='txtDateTimePicker' />`

javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y h:m tt',
        value: new Date()
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
      formatTime: 'h:i A',
      step: 15,  // Set the minute step to 15 minutes
      value: new Date()
    });
});
```

Comment: That served my purpose. Thank you. Could you please give me the documentation link for all the formats?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format :"DD/MM/YYYY h.m A",
 });
});
```